# os.system command in python reading improper for wifi name

Tags: python, string, os.system

Not 100% what to title this post. It is a pretty simple question though

First I ran:

```
os.system("netsh interface show interface")
```

figured out my wifi was called "Wi-fi 2"

Then I wanted to make 2 simple functions for turning it on and off

```
import os 

def enable():
    os.system("netsh interface set interface 'Wi-Fi 2' enabled")
def disable():
    os.system("netsh interface set interface 'Wi-Fi 2' disabled")
```

Also tried doing it a few other ways like

```
interface "+"Wi-Fi 2"+" disabled")
```

When I call disable though it gives me this error:

```
2 is not an acceptable value for admin.
The parameter is incorrect.
```

it is reading the 2 as a seperate parameter (have confirmed by trying Wi-Fi 3 and it says 3 is not an acceptable value).

Am I not doing this string proper somehow? No idea why this is happening, I would rather not have to rename the Wifi since thats just a poor work around instead of understanding the problem and fixing it.

Thanks

Comment: Most likely (since the adapter name contains spaces), you'd need to _dblquote_ it. In your code it should be like: `os.system("netsh interface set interface \"Wi-Fi 2\" enabled")`, or (even if I am not such a big fan of this form): `os.system('netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi 2" enabled')`. If this is the case, modify all the places.

Comment: Want to make this the answer so I can accept? It made it work, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Win* cmd shell (although this is not restricted to *Win*), *SPACE* (*ASCII* *0x20*(*32*)) is a **separator** (or: one of them), meaning that when parsing a sequence of characters when encountering a *SPACE*, what's before will be treated as one token, while what comes after it, will be treated as another token (and so on).

The *reverse* (if you will) is the *dblquote* (**"** or *ASCII* *0x22*(*34*)): what's contained between 2 such characters will be treated as one token, regardless if it contains *SPACE*s.

This applies to:

- File paths (that's why `dir c:\Program Files` fails, while `dir "c:\Program Files"` works - and the latter should be used)
- Command arguments (same thing here)

This is what needs to be done from *OS*'s perspective, we still need to handle the *Python* string (that wraps all this). It can be done in 2 ways as explained here:  [[Python]: String literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

- Escaping **"** by a *bkslash* (**\** or *ASCII* *0x5C*(*92*)), since the string is also enclosed by *dblquote*s: `os.system("netsh interface set interface \"Wi-Fi 2\" enabled")`
- Using the *single quote* (**'** or *ASCII* *0x27*(*39*)) to enclose the string: `os.system('netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi 2" enabled')`